# LeafletJS, can't bind popup to second marker

Tags: javascript, dictionary, geolocation, leaflet, marker

I can't bind a popup to a second marker whilst using LeafletJS, the first marker works perfectly fine, any help? Here's my javascript code:

```
        var map = L.map('mapScene', {
                zoomControl: false,
        attributionControl: false,
    }).fitWorld();

    var playerIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'img/playermarker.png',
        shadowUrl: 'img/marker-shadow.png',

        iconSize: [25, 41],
        iconAnchor: [12, 41],
        popupAnchor: [1, -34],
        shadowSize: [41, 41]
    });

        var itemsIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'img/crate.png',
        shadowUrl: 'img/marker-shadow.png',

        iconSize:     [45, 46], // size of the icon
        shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
        iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
        shadowAnchor: [10, 117],  // the same for the shadow
            popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    });



    L.tileLayer('http://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}', {
        minZoom: 14,
        maxZoom: 14,
        attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        ext: 'png'
    }).addTo(map);


   var playerMarker;

    function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;


       playerMarker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
            icon: playerIcon
        }).addTo(map).bindPopup("Hey i'm you!");

                addMarkers();
    }

        function addMarkers(){
            alert();

            L.marker(playerMarker + 2, {
                    icon: itemsIcon
            }).addTo(map).bindPopup("").on('popupopen', function() {
            alert();
            });
        }


    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);
    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);

    map.locate({
        setView: true,
        maxZoom: 16
    });
```

The second marker, added through the function "addMarkers()" show's up perfectly fine, but .bindpopup isn't working at all. You can click on the marker but nothing shows up, and neither does the alert.

Comment: `L.marker(playerMarker + 2, ...` is strange to me. Could you also explain what you are trying to do with your markers ? Why do you need to add two markers on the `locationfound` event ?

Comment: @JulienV Just simply adding the marker near the player's marker, though that's not relevant to the issue.

Comment: What does your browser console says? Like @JulienV implies, your code would likely throw errors.

Comment: @ghybs just checked, my code isn't throwing any errors.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/298/ besides the missing images, see the `TypeError: latlng is null` due to the `playerMarker + 2` line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @ghybs for the fiddle. Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/301/).
I don't know how you could have thought it would work with `playerMarker + 2` as a `latLng` but it appears it was the mistake. An addition between a marker and an integer cannot work.

[EDIT] Here is the interesting piece of code :

```
function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
    playerMarker = L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup("Hey i'm the first marker ");

    addMarkers();
}

function addMarkers() {
  //alert();
  var ll = playerMarker.getLatLng();
  var ll2 = L.latLng(ll.lat+12, ll.lng+12);
  var mm = L.marker(ll2).addTo(map);
  mm.bindPopup("Hey i'm the second marker");
}
```